# Keeping modified library files updated in git

Tags: git, github, shared-libraries, updates

I am using a file from a github project in my web module, but I have a few local changes.  I want to periodically pull in changes from the main branch, maintaining my local modifications.

To be more specific, I am using a file from [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases).  I updated it with a few changes that allow me to run it synchronously within my project.  Rather than just including the html2canvas.js file in my git project, I want some kind of link back to the github html2canvas project, so that I can merge in changes automatically by running some command.

Is this possible with git?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to include the whole html2canvas repository in your project. This will allow you to pull from that directory. You will need to stash all of your local changes before making a pull to keep them.